# Issue with the search page layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This doesn't quite look right:

[image]

Opera, FF, IE7, Safari, and Chrome. Check for yourself here:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/search
- https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in a fix, will be in the next deployment